# Migration issue from mysql to postgresql using pgloader

Tags: docker, postgresql-9.6, openproject, pgloader

While migrating from MySql to PostgreSQL it giving error-
INFO: Control stack guard page unprotected
Control stack guard page temporarily disabled: proceed with caution

```
pgloader mysql://root:root@localhost/opdb1 postgresql://postgres:root@localhost:5432/opdb
2019-11-04T11:40:48.116000Z LOG Migrating from #<MYSQL-CONNECTION mysql://root@localhost:3306/opdb1 {1009DAE7F3}
2019-11-04T11:40:48.125000Z LOG Migrating into #<PGSQL-CONNECTION pgsql://postgres@localhost:5432/opdb {1009F0C903} 
KABOOM! INFO: Control stack guard page unprotected Control stack guard page
  temporarily disabled: proceed with caution
```

What I am doing here?

Control stack exhausted (no more space for function call frames).
This is probably due to heavily nested or infinitely recursive function
calls, or a tail call that SBCL cannot or has not optimized away.

PROCEED WITH CAUTION.